# how to clear cache and cached template pages in Coldfusion8 (Apache 2.2)

Tags: apache, coldfusion, refresh, localhost

I'm going insane here... my first day with Coldfusion/MySQL running on a local Apache 2.2.0 webserver.

I have an

```
 index.cfm
```

file, which I took and modified, replacing 20k of code with just

```
 <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
```

But when I refresh the browser, the old index.cfm keeps coming up. No matter what I do...
- empty the file altogether
- disable browser cache
- clear ColdFusion Admin Panel Cache
- rename index.cfm to wtf.cfm

If I refresh.... same old index.cfm.

All other files are updated once I change them.

**Question:**
What am I missing? Must be Apache, because everything else makes no sense, doesn't it?

THANKS for ending my index.cfm-misery...!

**EDIT:**
I removed the whole application besides index.cfm. Refreshing now gives me *hello world*. I then added the Application.cfm, refreshed and I'm back to my full index.cfm...

Application.cfm looks like this:

```
... 
<CF_callLogin 
     datasource="dtb"
     TableName="table"
     UserField="user"
     ...  
 BGColor="FFFFFF">
```

So I guess this calls callLogin.cfm and passes along above parameters. Still I also deleted the callLogin.cfm after trying to edit it forever, so there shouldn't be anything.

Still clueless...

**EDIT2:**
Could be a **cf cache_pages**?
I now removed all files in wwwroot\WEB-INF\cfclasses as per http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:54088 let'see if this helps.... doesn't :-(

**EDIT3:**
Could be a **cached template**? - http://blogs.sanmathi.org/ashwin/2006/07/12/tangling-with-the-template-cache/ It is... See my answer below

Answer (score 4):

Wasted half a day...

It is a cached template and CF or Apache just seem to not give a *%&/$ if you edit or delete the file.

Here is the hack that worked for me:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/673-Force-ColdFusion-Server-To-Recompile-A-ColdFusion-Template.htm

= Generate a loong text, append it to the template, save, refresh and violá, all of a sudden your template is updated, as the file size changed enough to finally warrant an update of the template.

You also could try turning this off in development using the CF-Admin > Server Setting > Caching, but this did not work at all in my case (first place I started trying to delete...)

Anyway, maybe this saves someone else a day :-)

Comment: Marking this answer as the solution would help others avoid wasting their time on a solved issue...

Answer (score 0):

Restart Apache then see if resolved, then CF and see if resolved. I haven't run into an issue like this in CF that wasn't resolved after the CF service was restarted.

Comment: nope. I shut down Apache, then disabled CF8 SearchServer/ODBCServer/ODBCAgent and ApplicationSever and switched them back on one after the other. Once everthing is back up, I'm getting my index.cfm, which I had renamed to _index.cfm. I'm lost...

Comment: file still shows up... 1second I will edit some more info above